# Solenoid Valve Resistance

Tags: electrical-engineering, hydraulics

This is basic but will a DC solenoid have 0 Ohms impedance when energized? For example, a valve in the closed position with 24VDC applied to the solenoid. Don't inductors have zero impedance for steady DC applied?

Comment: if it had zero ohms, what would the amps in the circuit be?  I=V/R would be a problem

Comment: Yes I know this, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: Ideal inductors are theoretical. You can use them with a resistor in series to get a decent model of a real one, but in reality, resistance exists in the magnet wire itself.

Comment: solenoid is simply a coil of wire. As such it is not an ideal inductor. It has resistance, and capacitance between the windings.

Comment: So would a typical solenoid valve be wired in series with a resistor to limit the amount of current that can flow through?